# Как извлечь блоки текста регулярным выражением?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть файлы, содержащие первой строкой тему билетов.

Далее идут билеты.

Хочу получить содержимое каждого билета, включающее в том числе и номер билета.

```
import re
from typing import List

content = """\
Тема: Бла Бла Бла

Билет №1
1. валдывлдывладвылавыл
2. ldekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. dkjkdjksdjdsjfdsj

Билет №2
1. вwdsалдывлдывладвылавыл
2. asdladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. dkjkdjksdjdsjfdsj
4. ldekldkldkldkld dkfdk

Билет №3
1. sadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл
2. asdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. asddkjkdjk sdjdsjfdsj
4. s ldekldkldksaldkld dkfdk
5. edk jkdjksdjdsjfdsj

Билет №4
1. sdsadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл
2. Dasdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
"""


def quiz(s) -> List[str]:
    regexp = re.compile(r'Билет №\d{1,3}')
    return regexp.split(s)[1:]


for item in quiz(content):
    print(item, end='---')
```

Результат:

```
1. валдывлдывладвылавыл
2. ldekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. dkjkdjksdjdsjfdsj

---
1. вwdsалдывлдывладвылавыл
2. asdladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. dkjkdjksdjdsjfdsj
4. ldekldkldkldkld dkfdk

---
1. sadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл
2. asdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. asddkjkdjk sdjdsjfdsj
4. s ldekldkldksaldkld dkfdk
5. edk jkdjksdjdsjfdsj

---
1. sdsadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл
2. Dasdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
---
```

А я хочу, что получить информацию с номером билета, например:

```
Билет №3
1. sadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл
2. asdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk
3. asddkjkdjk sdjdsjfdsj
4. s ldekldkldksaldkld dkfdk
5. edk jkdjksdjdsjfdsj
```

Как этого добиться используя регулярные выражения?

Comment: `re.search(fr'Билет №{ticket_num}(?:\n(?!\n).*)*', content).group()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Да нет, всё работает - https://ideone.com/lMz6Hy

Comment: Ааа, действительно. Вы правы. Я думал опечатка, и удалил f

Comment: И гораздо быстрее чем `(?s)(Билет.*?)(?:[\r\n]{2,}|$)` - https://regex101.com/r/d0KQpN/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = re.findall(r"(Билет.*?)(?:[\r\n]{2,}|$)", content, flags=re.S)
```

Результат:

```
In [133]: res
Out[133]: 
['Билет №1\n1. валдывлдывладвылавыл\n2. ldekldkldkldkld dkfdk\n3. dkjkdjksdjdsjfdsj',
 'Билет №2\n1. вwdsалдывлдывладвылавыл\n2. asdladekldkldkldkld dkfdk\n3. dkjkdjksdjdsjfdsj\n4. ldekldkldkldkld dkfdk',
 'Билет №3\n1. sadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл\n2. asdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk\n3. asddkjkdjk sdjdsjfdsj\n4. s ldekldkldksaldkld dkfdk\n5. edk jkdjksdjdsjfdsj',
 'Билет №4\n1. sdsadвwdsалд ывлдывлад вылавыл\n2. Dasdsd ladekldkldkldkld dkfdk']
```